# Combine Regexp and set of values (hash/array) to compare if a string matches in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following pattern to check:

```
"MODEL_NAME"-"ID"."FORMAT_TYPE"
```

where, for example:

```
MODEL_NAME = [:product, :brand]
FORMAT_TYPE = [:jpg, :png]
```

First I wanted to check if the regexp is something like:

```
/^\w+-\d+.\w+$/
```

and I have also to check if the part of my string is part of my arrays. I want something more flexible than:

```
/^(product|brand)-\d+.(jpg|png)$/
```

which I could manage through my arrays. What is a good solution to do it?

Comment: `.` need to be escaped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/^(#{MODEL_NAME.join '|'})-\d+\.(#{FORMAT_TYPE.join '|'})$/
# => /^(product|brand)-\d+\.(jpg|png)$/
```